# Unable to instantiate the UIApplication subclass instance. No class named %@ is loaded

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am getting following error, as soon as the app is run it crashes without much info. Some information from the crash log is as follow. I already checked info.plist and it is correct. It used to be working, but once I clean built it and it suddenly stopped working in simulator. I don't remember changing any build settings. Only thing I changed was add new screen in the storyboard. I tried removing the screen but it didn't help.

```
0x10f83b578 <+442>:  leaq   0x8a7208(%rip), %rdx      ; "int UIApplicationMain(int, char **, NSString *, NSString *)"
0x10f83b57f <+449>:  callq  *%r12
0x10f83b582 <+452>:  movq   %rax, %r14
0x10f83b585 <+455>:  movq   0xdbbca4(%rip), %rdi      ; (void *)0x000000010f4948e0: NSString
0x10f83b58c <+462>:  movq   0xd8f7d5(%rip), %rsi      ; "stringWithUTF8String:"
0x10f83b593 <+469>:  leaq   0x8a68ef(%rip), %rdx      ; "/SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44.2/UIApplication.m"
0x10f83b59a <+476>:  callq  *%r12
0x10f83b59d <+479>:  movq   %rax, %rcx
0x10f83b5a0 <+482>:  movq   0xd909f9(%rip), %rsi      ; "handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:"
0x10f83b5a7 <+489>:  movq   %rbx, (%rsp)
0x10f83b5ab <+493>:  leaq   0xb8611e(%rip), %r9       ; @"Unable to instantiate the UIApplication subclass instance. No class named %@ is loaded."
```

Comment: Seems like you forgot to use String with format somewhere, %@ is place holder for a string... Just a thought

Comment: It used to be working, but once I clean built it and it suddenly stopped working in simulator. I don't remember changing any build settings. Only thing I changed was add new screen in the storyboard. I tried removing the screen but it didn't help.